# Приложение разбитое на пакеты. Доступ к Базе данных

Tags: база-данных, mvc, golang

Хочу сделать web приложение на golang, используя [ozzo](https://github.com/go-ozzo) фреймворк.
Если я разбиваю приложение на некие пакеты, то каким образом мне получить доступ к настройкам приложения и инстансу соединения с базой данных в этих пакетах?

Как лучше хранить мои модели? Отдельным пакетом в папке models (возможно, с подпапками) используя паттерн MVC, или же делать полностью законченные пакеты с доступом к базе данных в самих пакетах?

```
1. Вариант    
    /config
    /controllers
    /models
    /server
    main.go

2. Вариант
    /config
    /packages
    //user
    //posts
    //others...
    /server
    main.go
```

В первом случае хендлеры отдельно, модели отдельно.
Во втором случае пакеты полные. Там и обработка и доступ к необходимым данным из базы.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос по архитектуре приложения каждый разработчик решает для себя сам. Она может быть основана на особенностях всей информационной системы в целом или на личном опыте и предпочтении разработчика/архитектора.

Лично я бы склонялся больше к следованию MVC-архитектуры как наиболее устоявшейся в современном мире разработки ПО.

Попробуйте почитать вот [этот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/269893/) [цикл](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270351/) [статей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/271157/). Там описаны лучшие практики архитектуры ПО в разрезе Golang. Фреймворк не должен помешать построению архитектуры.

Comment: Последний проект реализовал согласно Clean Architecture, ощущения не передать, полное управление кодом, разделение доменной логики от инфаструктуры, легкая расширяемость, в общем, здоровская вещь, сейчас копаю в сторону DDD